# A large download is causing my server to completely crash. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Tags: server, ram, wget, curl

I recently got a VPS Ubuntu server. It only has 1GB of RAM but the reason why I got it is that it has gigabit so I'm using it as a quick downloader and then Dropbox uploader.

I've been trying to download the 13GB Wikipedia dump but when I use either wget or curl, it starts to download and gets about 10 seconds of a gigabyte in, but then the server totally dies. Just dead. I can't get it to boot back up. The only solution is to rebuild it. I have more than enough disk space and I'm trying it on a clean 16.04 install.

Has this happened to anyone else? I suspect it's because of the 1GB of RAM since another server I have on another provider with 2GB.

The commands I'm running:

```
curl -O http://dumps.wikimedia.your.org/enwiki/20161020/enwiki-20161020-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

and

`wget http://dumps.wikimedia.your.org/enwiki/20161020/enwiki-20161020-pages-articles.xml.bz2`